# Getting the position of an element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align an element to another one, for example I would like to reach that:

```
. Beer    25cl  5€
          50cl  7€
. wine    25cl  2€
          50cl  3€
```

With an html code similar to:

```
<li>
    <span class="item">Beer</span>
    <span class="size">25cl</span>
    <span class="badge">5€</span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <span class="size">50cl</span>          <!-- how to tell this to start at the same x position than the previous element of class "size" -->
    <span class="badge">7€</span>
</li>
```

I have seen a solution using a table, but I hope for a better solution (using a table for that seems like using a bazooka to kill a fly).

I have seen another solution using JS to retrieve the "left" property of an element, but it seems to work only if the left element is manually set, which is not the case here.

If relevant: I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Use Bootstrap Grid System!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Bootstraps grid layout - this will be responsive too.

I've converted your code for you here: http://www.bootply.com/L5EzpIO6X8

You can adjust the widths by changing the `col-lg-12` to different sizes. You can read more about the grid layouts [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

```
<ul> 
<li>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <span class="item">Beer</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="size">25cl</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="badge">5€</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="size">50cl</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="badge">7€</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <span class="item">Wine</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="size">25cl</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="badge">2€</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="size">50cl</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span class="badge">3€</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Edit

To answer your question about the bullet - to remove the "bullet" from the list in my example, you have to add a class to the containing `<ul>`.

**Bootstrap 2** It would be: `<ul class="unstyled">`

**Bootstrap 3** It would be: `<ul class="list-unstyled">`

I've updated my example (using Bootstrap 3).

### Edit 2

You can wrap the contents of the `<li>` in a div with the `clearfix` class to get the bullet on the right.

You can then adjust the vertical alignment by adjusting the margin of the new `<div>`. For example: `<div class="clearfix" style="margin-top -15px;">`

Comment: Did you noticed that the "." coming from the <li> is at the right of the price ?
Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: @taktak004 Sure, if you're using bootstrap you just need to change the containing `<ul>` to have the `list-unstyled` class. I've updated my answer and demo to show that. Or did you want the bullet to show on the left?

Comment: I want the bullet to show on the left. Is not that the default behavior ?

Comment: Yeah, it's on the right because the content is floating. I've updated the example to put it back on the left and also shown you how to adjust the vertical alignment.

Comment: Now it is on the left, but there is a vertical space between the point and the Beer. Where does that space come from ? How to remove it ?

Comment: I already showed that at the end of my answer (under Edit 2).

Comment: Hum, but how can you be sure that the -15px will be what is needed on every device ?
Is not there any better solution ?